# Merge points from multiple features that share common attribute

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, modelbuilder, features, merge

I have several point feature classes that all share similar attribute structure. How might I extract the points from all 9 feature classes that share a specific attribute?

Background: There are 9 different assessment areas for studying streams - each was studied at different dates so the data for photo points are stored in separate feature classes. I'd like to merge all the photo points into a single feature.

Comment: Do you have common fields for these 9 feature classes? Geographically speaking, you can just select your points from each class and copy and paste it into a new feature class. If your tables all have common fields that makes it easier. If you don't there a few options but let's see what your table is like first.

Comment: Use the Append tool if the fields are identical or use the Merge tool if they are not.  The Merge tool would add fields as necessary to cover all of the input data fields.  You then could clean that up if multiple variations in a field name really consolidate to a single field name.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is a common field between them all:

[Merge all the feature classes together](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/merge.htm) into one feature class

[Dissolve the feature class](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/dissolve.htm) based on the identifier field. This will result in a multi-point feature class with each entry comprised of multiple locations

Run [feature to point](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/feature-to-point.htm) to collapse the multipoint to point